# Sectioned bibliographies references not in order of appearance

Tags: bibliographies, lyx

I am currently writing my thesis using Lyx and I was wondering if anyone could help with an issue I am having with sectioned bibliographies.

I have the box checked for sectioned bibliographies to have the reference list at the end of each chapter however the reference order in the text is not in order of appearance. So the main body of text will read with references like [1, 8 , 4] for example. I have searched around online for a while for solutions but  can't get any of them to work. Could anybody here help?

Here is my LaTeX preamble if that's useful:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pslatex}
\renewcommand{\ps@plain}{\pagestyle{fancy}}
\lhead{}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\rfoot{}
\date{}
% sets caption sizes to less than textwidth
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{width=0.8\textwidth}
    \usepackage[margin=20pt,font=small,labelfont=bf,labelsep=endash]{caption}
% allows grouping of equations
\usepackage{amsmath}
% Compressing the reference numbers to [1-5]
\usepackage{notoccite}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
```

Thanks everyone

Comment: Quote: "LyX 1.4 has native support for the bibtopic package, which produces sectionated bibliographies (**please note that bibtopic does not support unsorted bibliographies**)." So are you using `bibtopic`?

Comment: Well I am using Lyx 2.2 but I am assuming it's the same. I am using the built in bibliography section Document>settings>Bibliography> sectioned bibliography. How would I go about using a different package and which would be most suitable for having a bibliography at the end of each chapter? Thanks

Comment: Yes, that selects `bibtopic`. The LyX documentation has some information (but not very clear, I'm afraid) about using `bibunits` instead. Then you must **not** select `sectioned bibliography`, but insert some LaTeX code. See https://wiki.lyx.org/Examples/Bibunits

Comment: Ah I see, I will have a look into this thanks very much for the help.